# My AngularJs app won't forward to another site

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an anchor tag whose `onclick()` should forward to an authentication server to log my user out. But nothing I do to redirect is working. The browser just forwards back to the same page.

Here's my HTML:

```
<a on-click=logOut() href="#">(Log Out)</a>
```

And the corresponding typescript:

```
document.location.href = this.logoutUrl+"?ERIGHTS_TARGET="+this.redirectUri, true;
```

I've also tried setting `window.location.href`, as well as `window.location.hash`. I'm pretty sure the "#" in the anchor has something to do with my problem, but I don't have enough javascript expertise to know what. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `on-click="logOut()"`, you forgot the quotes around the value. Possibly you might also need a component reference but that depends on if you are working in a controller or component: `on-click="$ctrl.logOut()"`

If you want to stop the default action (redirect in this case) pass in the event arguments.

```
on-click="logOut($event)"
```

and then modify the function to call `preventDefault()` on the argument.

```
function logOut(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // rest of code
}
```

Comment: I had hoped that was it, but it's not. You're right, the quotes were missing, but I debugged this and it goes into that method even without the quotes. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user1660256 - the default action on an anchor tag is to open the associated url defined in the `href` attribute. Passing in the event argument and calling [preventDefault](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp) cancels that action so you do not get a page reload.